# How spring manages threads for multiple api requests

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am working on spring project. I put `Thread.sleep(60000)` on one api to check thread safety. If I call that api then all other apis wait for that time. I thought every api request processed by separate threads. So what is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: The bean in spring is singleton by default. I think this may be a problem. Add a `@RequestScope` to bean and check again.

Comment: Spring doesn't. Tomcat does. There is no guarantee about the relationship between threads and requests.

Comment: @EJP I suppose this would have been solves with `http-thread-pool size` with glassfish, any similar option in tomcat ? Just asking, not an expert in this domain...

Comment: How this relates Couchbase?

Comment: @AxelH  thank you. The issue solved when I set thread-pool-size in tomcat.

Comment: @navintb So there is a thread pool in tomcat ^^. Here is a duplicate, this should answer your problem (confirm please) if not I will write an answer later.

Comment: @AxelH Issue resolved when I set maxThreads in tomcat server.xml file.

Comment: @avsej I didn't know if this behaviour was related to spring, tomcat or couchbase. Thats why I included couchbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved when I set maxThreads in tomcat server.xml file. 
Thank you all for helping me resolve this issue.